# jQuery: toggle a class and replace with another - vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display my modal by adding a "show" class to display it and if my modal has the class show and that I reclick, replace it with a "hide" class to remove it. I need this solution to add some CSS animation effects.

How can I do that please? Example: I click on my trigger class, "show" class is added to my modal to display it and if I reclick to my trigger, remove my "show" class and add "hide". And vice-versa.

my js code:

```
(function($)
{
    // MODAL
    $(".modal-trigger").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".modal").toggleClass("show");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Change IIFE syntax to doc ready block.

Answer (score 7):

Just start with one class on the `.modal` element, and toggle both, and they will alternate

```
$(".modal-trigger").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".modal").toggleClass("show hide");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5zkxsxy4/)

Comment: No, I don't want this: http://prntscr.com/a1gptf If show is added to my modal class, this is because my modal is displayed and I don't want hide it.

Comment: Then just start with the `.hide` class ?

Comment: I want only a class on my modal element, not "show hide".

Comment: You'll only have one class on your element, either `show` or `hide`

Comment: Oh, this is just easy to do... Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's the easy way of doing it, just start with one class, and toggle both, and they will **alternate**. Otherwise you'd have to do this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/5zkxsxy4/2/**